Is there a "correct way" of creating PLC project templates in TwinCAT3?
I was wondering if there is a way, and what is the correct way, of creating PLC templates. By default in TwinCAT you are provided with "Empty" and "Standard" projects - empty one is useless since it does not even include basic libraries and once you add task reference you start to scratch your head with all the errors (Tc3_Module needs to be added manually for tasks to work).
I took a dive to see how TwinCAT creates the templates and went ahead and created a PLC template by modifying existing TwinCAT files as well as adding my own files to achieve my goal. Long story short, here is the result:

As mentioned, I had to fiddle with files located in C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Components\Plc\PlcTemplates\1.0.0.0\Plc Templates, which I am not a fan of, and I assume once I update TwinCAT all these folder are deleted and contents will be lost, thus requring a script to do this again on do it manually. Has anyone created PLC templates before, or do people just do "Add existing item" and have a project defined there?

In all the 21 years I’ve used Beckhoff, I’ve never wanted this.
How ever I came to say: “empty project” Is used for creating libraries, as you don’t want tasks and other overheads.
Sorry I can’t answer your templates question… it’s got me thinking though.

How would you test or even compile an empty project though (POUs not instantiated in a task referenced program arent compiled or checked by the compiler)? As for the question, it is not something I would need, but it is something that would be useful to have, especialy when creating libraries or similar projects and to have a consistent project structure.
